# Shortests weighted path with Neo4j.rb and Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j, cypher, neo4j.rb

I am trying to calculate the shortest weighted path between two nodes.
Here's my User class:

```
class User
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode
  property :name, type: String
  has_many :both, :friends, rel_class: :Friendship, model_class: :User
end
```

Users are nodes and the relationship between them is:

```
class Friendship
  include Neo4j::ActiveRel

  before_save :set_weight
  from_class :User
  to_class :User
  type 'FRIENDSHIP'
  property :weight

  def set_weight
    ...
  end
```

The property weight is the value of the haversine distance between both nodes.

I figured out how to write the query to get all the paths that conect user_a with user_b:

```
all_paths = a.query_as(:a).match_nodes(b: b).match('p=((a)-[*]-(b))').pluck(:p)
```

And I'm sure that I can chain methods to this query to get the shortest path based on the weight but I couldn't find the right Cypher syntax so I ended iterating every path and calculating the total weight for each path to get the shortest one:

```
def shortest_weighted_path(start_user_id, end_user_id)
  a = User.find(start_user_id)
  b = User.find(end_user_id)

  all_paths = a.query_as(:a).match_nodes(b: b).match('p=((a)-[*]-(b))').pluck(:p)
  paths_and_weights = {}
  all_paths.each_with_index do |path, index|
    total_weight = 0
    path.relationships.each { |relationship| total_weight = total_weight + relationship.properties[:weight] }
    paths_and_weights[index] = total_weight
  end
  paths_and_weights = paths_and_weights.sort_by {|_key, value| value}.to_h
  shortest_path_index = paths_and_weights.keys.first
  shortest_path = all_paths[shortest_path_index]

  nodes_in_path = []
  shortest_path.nodes.each { |node| nodes_in_path << node.properties[:uuid] }
  nodes_in_path
end
```

Googling some more I found and example on how to calculate the shortest path with Cypher:

```
START  startNode=node:node_auto_index(name={startNode}),
   endNode=node:node_auto_index(name={endNode})
MATCH  p=(startNode)-[:CONNECTED_TO*1..4]->(endNode)
RETURN p AS shortestPath, 
       reduce(weight=0, r in relationships(p) : weight+r.weight) AS   totalWeight
     ORDER BY totalWeight ASC
     LIMIT 1
```

So my question is: how can I write this query for Neo4j.rb based in my User-Friendship example?

Comment: You can use https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-graph-algorithms, where the weighted shortest path algorithm is already implemented

Comment: it sounds great! do you know how to make it work in a Ruby On Rails project?

Comment: @Ibrah It's a Neo4j plugin. [install](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-graph-algorithms#installation) it to your Neo4j server, and then you will be able to use the functions in Cypher ([example](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-graph-algorithms#label-and-relationship-type-projection))

Comment: Thanks @Tezra , could you add it as an answer so I can upvote it?

Comment: @TomažBratanič Can you put that as an answer? I'm not familiar with that plugin, or how to use it.